# abstract HttpFileCollectionBase

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got a few places in my MVC3 application where a user can upload a file. Each time a file is uploaded a few things must take place. Associating it with the user, writing to an activity log, etc... I'd like to abstract/refactor the functionality so I don't have file upload code in 3 different places but I can't figure out how to abstract the HttpFileCollectionBase.

I don't want to have to to include a reference to System.Web in the library that handles this. Any suggestions? My only thought was writing the file to a Stream and wrapping that in a class to include content type and other properties I may need.

Here's a method stub for what I'm looking for

public void AttachFiles(Assignment assignment, User user, String message, File file)

Thoughts...?

Comment: You're writing an ASP.NET application. What's wrong with referencing `System.Web.dll`?

Comment: Agree with marcind: what other contexts would a file upload handler be used other then a web application?

Comment: I suppose there's nothing wrong with it. System.Web just seems like a rather large dependency to add while I was trying to keep my Interface light. I think I'll go down this road, I can always come back to it later. The key is that I'm finally refactoring this out to remove some duplication. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to abstract HttpFileCollectionBase - you could create an extension method for HttpFileCollectionBase - if you are using C# 4 .